# unable to import module named pandas

Tags: python, pandas, import, module

I have python 2.7 and python 3 installed.

I also have pip2.7 and pip3 installed.

I use IPython Notebook in the Jupyter console. Using the console I can use every module I want but I'm trying to use the terminal :

```
python script.py arg1 arg2
```

I have installed pandas 0.17.1 in both versions of python.

Then I launch my script in the terminal and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                             
  File "script.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                                                
     import pandas as pd                                                                                                                        
 ImportError: No module named pandas
```

and yet when running

```
pip install pandas
pip2.7 install pandas
```

it says:

```
 requirement already satisfied
```

How can I enable pandas to be imported in my script running in Terminal ?
Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? Are you sure that one of your pip commands actually belongs to one of your listed python versions?

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you install IPython notebook and Jupyter?

Comment: I am working on a cluster, not a virtual environment. The cluster is working on Linux Redhat. How can I check that pip commands belong to one of my python versions ?

Comment: Check if pip3 install pandas makes the import work.

Answer (score 0):

try first to uninstall pandas

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip2.7 uninstall pandas
```

and then try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    pip install numpy
    pip install pandas
```

pip install django-pandas

django-pandas supports Django (>=1.4.5)

In some cases it is required to install numpy in your virtual

Answer (score 0):

try the below command(this is for ubuntu 16.04)

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time when you are using `env` named pandas this error might happend.

Comment: Please go through [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Be sure to add essential details/steps in you answer.